# V-for to work with nested arrays where the component renders as much as the length of the parent array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, nested-loops, nested-lists, v-for

I have a nested array of objects and the structure is as follows:

`selectedSystems = [[{name: 'James', systemID: 1}], [{name: 'John', systemID: 2}, {name: 'Emily', systemID: 3}], [{name: 'Rachel', systemID: 5}]]`

What I am trying to achieve is display the names in as many boxes as the size of the parent array (selectedSystems) So Box1 will have just James, box 2 has John and emily and then box 3 has Rachel and for v-model I am using the index of the selectedSystem inside the child element. so selectedSystem[0] is the v-model for the first box as it contains . I get the no key passed error for `v-for` Any other way to do this/ make it simpler would be more appreciated.

can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by boxes ? It's an input field ? If Yes, what do you mean by `box 2 has John and emily` ?

Comment: Hey Rohit, one box is a v-autocomplete that allows you to pick multiple items inside a text-field. 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/

Comment: Each array in selectedSystems is an auto complete ? Can you please help me in understanding the final output ? May be with a small diagram or a flow.